# Cannot use 'in' operator to search for JSONPath Online Evaluator

Tags: json, jsonpath, json-path-expression

Cannot use 'in' operator to search for JSONPath Online Evaluator.   Can you you please help me why is throwing error message ?   Is it syntax error ?

[image]

Comment: in means searching an array for a value but @.category is not an array.  In this case you just want `$.store.book[?(@.category == 'fiction')]`

Comment: If you make each `category` an array then `$.store.book[?('fiction' in @.category)]` won't work on https://jsonpath.com/ (and neither will multiple array filters).  However, they will work on https://www.javainuse.com/jsonpath so I have started using the second site in preference to the first.